# makefile doesn't reuse variables as expected

Tags: variables, makefile, reusability

Makefile

```
SRC := a

first: $(SRC)
        @echo $(SRC)
        @echo "$@ $<"

SRC := b

second: $(SRC)
        @echo $(SRC)
        @echo "$@ $<"
```

Why does it echo "b"?

```
make first
b
first a
```

Thanks,
Ron

I'm trying to reuse variables in a Makefile and expected variables to have the value most recently assigned.

Comment: Make does not process a makefile the same way that (for example) Python or JavaScript process source files.

Comment: Makefiles are not as linear as you might link.  They are "declarative".  The `$(SRC)` element doesn't get substituted until it is needed, which happens after the whole file has been scanned.  All of the `$(SRC)` values will be substituted with the final value of `SRC`.

Comment: The comment by @TimRoberts is not quite correct. It is true that make variables are only expanded when needed, but it's not the case that this is always after the whole file has been scanned.  The rules for expansion are described in the GNU make manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html  This should explain the behavior you see.